# Changing column header in SSRS doesn't show updated name when exporting to csv

Tags: csv, reporting-services

I have a simple table in a SSRS report that users need to export to csv.  After creating the report I changed a few of the column header names in the table.  The report shows up fine when running it, but once a user exports to csv, it shows the old default column header name.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: is there anyway so that you dont have to have the textbox column name? id perfer not to have anything, as im trying to just create a csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSV headers are derived from the names of the textboxes that make up the cells of the grid. Make sure you change these appropriately.