# How to change exported headers from report builder

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have inherited a database that has some field names that have either been misspelled or repurposed somehow.

The report builder report has the corrections when viewed on screen, but when exporting to CSV, the field names come through as the column headers instead of the report column headings.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing column header in SSRS doesn't show updated name when exporting to csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894385/changing-column-header-in-ssrs-doesnt-show-updated-name-when-exporting-to-csv)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this did solve my problem.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment mentioned that the names of the text boxes are what get exported as column headers on a CSV file.  I changed this and it is working as expected now.

Thank you AHiggins